does pyside6 support bindable properties?
I am looking for a reactive programming mechanism like the Vue framework, and I know that QML has two-way binding just like Vue, but I want to use it in QWidget, I found a pyside6 document.
but it's Cpp version.I try to add bindable keyword and try to find QProperty in pyside6,
@Property(bool, bindbable=True)  # raise keyword error
def property(self):
    ...

both didn't work, can I use it in pyside6? Or this function just has no python binding?If not, why this document is in pyside6's page?

Almost all PySide docs are fundamentally a copy of the C++ ones, and we often discourage to use them to begin with. It's mostly generated from the C++ API, some classes/functions do not (or could not) even exist in Python, many code snippets are automatically "translated" to Python and often unreliable. I frankly believe those docs shouldn't have existed to begin with, as they're often misleading and an unnecessary duplicate 99% of the times. Anyhow, right now bindable properties don't seem supported, and considering how the Python library binding works, I'm not even sure they will ever be.
